# Какой хук в Wordpress отвечает за обновление плагина?

Tags: wordpress

Например, в моей новой версии плагина я бы хотел выполнить миграции для базы данных.

Какой для этого хук. [register_activation_hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) для этой цели не подойдет, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Номер текущей версии плагина обычно пишут в опцию. Если в опции версия не соответствует текущей, то выполняют миграцию и обновляют опцию.

Проверка опции, таким образом, нужна при каждой загрузке плагина. Но это ничего не стоит, потому что опции по умолчанию autoload и все грузятся одним запросом при старте ядра.